# Batch set entries as draft?

Tags: entries

I have 900 entries that I have imported via the excellent [import](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import) plugin. I need these to be set as draft (or 'disabled' status). Is there any way I can do this programatically? I don't fancy doing it manually.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this in the issues for the plugin and got a very prompt reply, the solution offered works perfectly:

https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import/issues/15